# What does this circuit do? How can I repurpose / modify it for my needs?

Tags: amplifier, rf, analog, receiver

Can someone explain what this circuit does? It is a 433 MHz RF module receiver that is supposed to work with digital signals.

My goal would be to find out if it can be used to receive analog AM signals. As far as I can tell it is just an amplifier circuit with an amplifier IC. I am not so sure why the Q2 transistor and the L0 + C7 LC circuit is needed, so if someone could tell me that would be great.

It seems to me that it should work for what I want it to do, but I hope someone will be able to give a more professional thought.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What AM signal do you expect to find at 433 MHz?

Comment: I will transmit it myself with the transmitter module. That should be relatively easy to modify that oscillator circuit.

Comment: Do you plan to build it yourself, or to modify an existing module?

Comment: I will modify this transmitter circuit to send composite video signal with AM modulation.
http://www.hobbycomponents.com/images/forum/MX-05V.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not so sure why the Q2 transistor and the L0 + C7 LC circuit is
> needed, so if someone could tell me that would be great.

It's a [superegenerative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_circuit) receiver, which amplifies the signal with positive feedback until it breaks into oscillation (at which point the gain is 'infinite') then quenches the oscillation at a supersonic frequency. This causes Q2's average Emitter current to vary proportionally to the signal strength, which demodulates AM signals.

L0 and C7 form a tuned circuit that sets the receiving (and oscillating) frequency.

Q1 and associated parts are an RF amplifier, which increases the signal strength to reduce noise, and isolates the oscillator from the antenna (reduces radiated emissions).

The demodulated audio signal is amplified by the 2nd (bottom) half of the LM358 dual op amp IC, then converted to a square wave in the 1st (top) half, which is configured as a comparator with hysteresis.

You can extract the audio signal from pin 7 of the LM358. However it will be very distorted because the input is biased at 0 V. To work properly pin 5 should be biased at about half the supply voltage, and the bottom end of R14 should be connected to ground via a capacitor to block DC.

Comment: Thanks @Bruce !
I did not specify it, but I was planning to receive a composite video signal. Would it still work with that sort of signal?
If I understand correctly a 10K pullup resistor at pin 5 should set the bias to half of the VCC and a capacitor between GND and R14 should do the job.

Comment: The receiver and the old LM358 opamp demodulate low audio frequencies not high video frequencies.

Comment: For composite video the quench frequency would have to much higher (>6MHz) and it probably wouldn't work well. Better to use a standard TV receiver on an appropriate TV channel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_television